# Grease Pencil - How to virtually divide the canvas into equal parts?

Tags: grease-pencil

I would like to draw 2d assets for video games on Blender. For that, I chose my resolution, for example, 540x180. However, I need to know how to divide those pixels into 3 equal parts of 180x180 pixels. The division is just for visualization. Is it possible to draw vertical parallels ? Or to turn the grid on with 3 visible squares ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Camera settings → Viewport display → Composition Guides

You can enable **Thirds** for 3x3 grid and **Center** for 2x2 grid.

[image]

[image]

You can also get some adjustable lines using safe areas:

[image]

[image]